# Angular material Date validation not happening as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-datepicker

I am working on `mat-datepicker` where the User can enter the value and choose the date with my code It's working properly. I have an update button by default it will be in disabled mode. When the user met two conditions true then only the update button will enable.

Here is my screenshot it will look like

[image]

If I clear the last date the update button will be in disable mode once the user enter the last date then only the update will enable **here I got an issue**

Here is my ts code

```js
dateValidator(input) {
    //console.log(input);
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate(), input.length > 0)
    if (!!input) { // null check
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]' && !this.disableDate() && input.length > 0) {
            this.disableUpdateBtn = false;
            console.log("Date is Valid!!");
        } else {
        this.disableUpdateBtn = true;
        console.log("Date is Invalid!!");
        }
    } else {
        this.disableUpdateBtn = true;
        console.log("Date is Invalid!!");
    }
}
```

Here is my `HTML` code for the Update button

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="updateMilestone();" cdkFocusInitial [disabled]="disableUpdateBtn">
    Update
</button>
```

I am getting the error when I click the clear button, then I start typing the date, and then I type `01`. I am not getting any error but when I start typing `Dec`.

[image]

I was checking even null for input in the if condition Why still this is **cannot read the null properties**

Comment: I believe tying the elements to a reactive form and then adding in validation on the formcontrol the angular way may alleviate this problem, since it should be easier to check the value during validation

Comment: One option that may also help is to set validation on blur.
updateOn: "blur" on the formcontrols.

Comment: The null check is after the console log. The error is triggered there.

Comment: Remove the line `console.log(Object.prototype.toStrin....);`

Comment: You are trying to read property `length` before checking for null value, delete the preceding console log

Comment: what is implementation of disableDate()

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this: `input.length` to: `input?.length` in your code (all instances)

Comment: Safe navigation operator is a pretty new feature of Typescript (3.7 and above), I would not assume that he's on a compatible release.

Answer (score 1):

The error appearing on the console is on the `console.log` line (which is before the `null` check):

```js
dateValidator(input) {
    // error on the next line, because `input` is `null`, and you're trying to read the `length`.
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate(), input.length > 0)
    if (!!input) { // null check
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In order to get around this, either:

1. Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) by changing all your instances of `input.length` to `input?.length`.

```js
dateValidator(input) {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate(), input?.length > 0)
    if (!!input) { // null check
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

2. Or, move the `console.log` line inside the `if` null check scope.

```js
dateValidator(input) {
    if (!!input) { // null check
        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Date]', !this.disableDate(), input.length > 0)
    }
    ...
}
```

3. Or, simply remove the `console.log` line.